# Trouble importing encrypted LTSpice model in to ADS

Tags: ltspice, ads

I'm new to ADS. I've outgrown what is practical to accomplish in LTSpice though. I have a diode that I need to do a load-pull and source-pull analysis on in a high frequency domain. I've worked with the diode in LTSpice and the manufacturer's model is surprisingly good in terms matching physical measurements at high frequency (>500MHz). The problem is that their provided model is encrypted. When I try to import into ADS, regardless of whether I try PSpice or HSpice or LTSpice options, I get a whole bunch of 'internal' components, most of which are SDD2P elements. What I don't get are any device ports and that's the obvious first problem. Can't do anything without ports to connect to and I get a ghostbuster 'no port' generic symbol for the imported device. I've tried reasoning out the netlist from all the internal components that are generated, but honestly it seems like there are way too many components for a Schottky diode. Would expect to see a handful, maybe up to a dozen depending on how they are modeling the device, but not 60 disparate components. So no ports is an obvious problem, but I feel like I'm just getting garbage out in general.

I'm trying to import as schematic, but I've tried importing as netlist and I get a ton of 'skipping unrecognized element' for various lines of encrypted hex. I've tried setting the 'reference technology definition' option to within the .lib file I'm importing, but it says there are no units defined in the file. I've also tried using HSpice import 'wizard' and didn't get any further with that. I have reached out to the device manufacturer's technical support and gotten no response.

Here is the model I am trying to use in ADS. It's a SiC Schottky from GeneSic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://genesicsemi.com/sic-schottky-mps/GB02SLT12-214/GB02SLT12-214_SPICE.zip

Comment: If it's been encrypted by the manufacturer, you probably won't be decrypting the model. Connect the manufacturer and see if they have an ads model

Comment: An encrypted LTspice subcircuit can only be decrypted by LTspice itself. Any output you get from importing it into ADS is erroneous. The only info you can deduce from an encrypted LTspice subcircuit is if you run a basic `.op` simulation in LTspice with minimal components (bare chip, current source into diode, no resistors, Tj grounded). This only gives you an extremely vague look of what's inside (look at the Error Log). In this example, it shows there is only one semiconductor diode model inside and the matrix size (i.e. number of internal nodes) is 13.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7TiX.png

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful trick to know even if it doesn't solve the problem. I haven't been able to get any resolution from manufacturer. I think most SiC foundries are just so busy they aren't super worried about customer support at the moment. SiC Schottkys are flying off the shelves as soon as distributors get them in. Looks like I'll be brute forcing a source/load pull in LTSpice.

Comment: Have you tried calling the office phone number and getting hold of an actual person?  Might have to wait until Tuesday, though, when the holidays are over.  +1 (703) 996-8200